# Sequelize - Sqlite - Problem with Associations

Tags: node.js, join, orm, sqlite, sequelize.js

(sorry for my english)

hi all,

i have created a project with sequelize and i have a problem with the model's association.

I have this models (created from a existing sqlite db with sequelize-auto):

```
//Genders.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Genders', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        Type: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'Genders'
    });
};

//Cities.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Cities', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        ExternalId: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        Name: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        Province: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        Description: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'Cities'
    });
};

//Persons.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Persons', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        Name: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        Surname: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true
        },
        BirthCity: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: 'Cities',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        Gender: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: 'Genders',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        ResidenceCity: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: 'Cities',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'Persons'
    });
};
```

then, after the authenticate, i import the modules with this code:

```
Persons = db.sequelize.import(__dirname+"/models/Persons.js");
Cities = db.sequelize.import(__dirname+"/models/Cities.js");
Genders = db.sequelize.import(__dirname+"/models/Genders.js");
```

and set the associations:

```
Persons.hasMany(Cities, {as: 'BirthCityField', foreignKey: 'BirthCity', sourceKey: 'id'});
Persons.hasMany(Cities, {as: 'ResidenceCityField',foreignKey: 'ResidenceCity', sourceKey: 'id'});
Persons.hasMany(Genders, {foreignKey: 'Gender', sourceKey: 'id'});
Genders.belongsTo(Persons, {foreignKey: 'Gender', targetKey: 'id'});
Cities.belongsTo(Houseds, {foreignKey: 'BirthCity', targetKey: 'id'});
Cities.belongsTo(Houseds, {foreignKey: 'ResidenceCity', targetKey: 'id'});
```

Then i have created this function:

```
function getPersonBySurname(search) {
    return  Persons.findAll({
        where : {
            Surname : {
                [Op.like] : search+'%'
            }
        },
        include : [Genders]
    });
}
```

when i call the function with for example search='fr', don't return nothing and the log is:

```
SELECT `Persons`.`id`, 
`Persons`.`Name`, 
`Persons`.`Surname`, 
`Persons`.`BirthDate`, 
`Persons`.`BirthCity`, 
`Persons`.`Gender`, 
`Persons`.`Nationality`, 
`Persons`.`ResidenceCity`, 
`Persons`.`Address`, 
`Persons`.`DocumentType`, 
`Persons`.`DocumentNumber`, 
`Persons`.`FiscalCode`, 
`Persons`.`createdAt`, 
`Persons`.`updatedAt`, 
`Persons`.`OwnerHoused`, 
`Persons`.`ComponentHoused`, 
`Genders`.`id` AS `Genders.id`, 
`Genders`.`Type` AS `Genders.Type`, 
`Genders`.`createdAt` AS `Genders.createdAt`, 
`Genders`.`updatedAt` AS `Genders.updatedAt`, 
`Genders`.`Gender` AS `Genders.Gender` 
FROM `Persons` AS `Persons` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Genders` AS `Genders` ON `Persons`.`id` = `Genders`.`Gender` 
WHERE `Persons`.`Surname` LIKE 'fr%';
```

I noticed that the 'join' is reversed.
indeed the 'join' must be

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Genders` AS `Genders` ON `Persons`.`Gender` = `Genders`.`id`
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

if i resolve this problem, my next question is: 
i have in Persons 2 foreign key with the same reference table (Cities),
in this case it is enough to call a single include?
For example:

```
function getPersonBySurname(search) {
    return  Persons.findAll({
        where : {
            Surname : {
                [Op.like] : search+'%'
            }
        },
        include : [Genders, Cities]
    });
}
```

thanks

Jempus

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good,

I think you might be missing the `then` , as `Model.findAll` returns the `Promise` ,

```
getPersonBySurname().then(data =>{
    console.log(data); //<----- Check here
});
```

So it will console log it out either `[]` or `array of data`.

As an answer to your second question , **[DO READ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494663/2349407)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I call the function in the another module, and i use the promise but I do not get an answer either in 'then' nor in 'catch'.
but in the sheel i have the log that i write ('SELECT `Persons`.`id`,........').
the sql query is wrong.